# Doctrine 2 flush update

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to update an entity with Doctrine. To remove or add, I have no problems, just to update. To do this I use the following code:

```
    $type = $app['em']->getRepository("\Model\Type")->find($id);

    $type->setCode("C2");

    $app['em']->persist($type);
    $app['em']->flush();

    echo $type->getCode(); // I get "C2"
```

But the data are not updated in the database. Why?

Thank you in advance,